# Windows 7 harddisk partition problem

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I am unable to open my D: partition(has vista installed on it) .. but i can play movies,music,etc in D:\Users folder.

Double-clicking 'D:' in MyComputer gives Access Denied error and Alt-enter shows its size and free-space as zero.

The disk management is showing D: as System,Active,Primary Partition.
And i am trying all these things in Windows 7 installed on the C: partition.

Comment: More info please. System model.make, 1 hard drive or two? Partition sizes? hat was installed first?

Answer (score 2):

Question - if you go My Computer-Right Click on D: and go to properties, then security, for all the various users, what are your rights?  The \Users folder usually gives Everyone rights to it whereas the root usually restricts rights to Administrators, or those who are logged into the OS.  If you had a username/password for the Vista partition and a different username/password for the Win7 partition, then the root of the Vista partition may be inaccessible, whereas the Users folder might not be.

Comment: Agreed.  It has the distinct stench of a permissions problem.

Comment: yeah... it says 'You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings.'
how i do get rid of it now??